# Laravel 8 Validation rule not working for unique email error always returning false

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to insert customer data where the email will be unique. Here is the mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_address` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `customer_email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `post_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer_phone` int NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `customer_email` (`customer_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
COMMIT;
```

Here the customer model:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table="customers";
    protected $fillable = ['customer_name', 'customer_email','customer_address', 'customer_city','customer_postcode'];
 }
```

And in the controller:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            [
            'customer_name' => 'required',
            'customer_address' => 'required',
            'customer_email' => "required|unique:customers",
            'customer_city' => 'required',
            'post_code' => 'required',
            'customer_phone' => 'required',
        ]);

            var_dump($validator->fails());
```

The `$validator->fails()` always returns false. What i am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the `POST` request contains `customer_email`

Comment: Can you dump `$request->all()` so we can see what's being validated please?

Comment: + You need to skip the current ID when updating the payload.

Comment: Here is the dump Array
`(
    [customer_name] => Muntashir Are Rahi
    [customer_address] => Dhaka, 726/25/A
    [customer_city] => Dhaka
    [post_code] => 1207
    [customer_email] => muntashir.rahi@gmail.com
    [customer_phone] => 01712552303
)`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, how to do that?

Comment: Right now it should work. Add a `dd($validator->errors());` so we can see what's exactly the problem here. Stupid question maybe, but are you sure the mail hasn't already been used? And it's an insert, not an update?

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper unique validation method.

1: you have to add "unique" validation.
2: define table name like "registrations".
3: define column name like "primary_contact".

> $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
> 'primary_contact' =>  'unique:registrations,primary_contact,null,null
> ]);

Comment: `'customer_email' => 'unique:customers,customer_email,null,null',` Not working

Comment: this should not happen after using this code.
show me your complete code and error please.